# Don't reinstall if gem is already installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I prevent `gem install` to not reinstall a Gem if the same version is already installed?

Comment: use `bundle` with Gemfile

Comment: In this case I don't want to use bundler. I need some cli tools.

Comment: When someone answers your question, accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--conservative` flag with gem install.

`gem install sqlite -v 1.3.8 --conservative`

It won't install or update any gems that meet the version requirement.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need. Should be default behavior in my opinion.

Comment: I agree. It was only while trying this out that I realised it wasn't the default.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with some bash oneliner:

`if ! gem list | grep your_gem_name; then gem install your_gem_name; fi;`